# Implode error for PHP

Tags: php, implode

I have a form where I've got three checkboxes like this:

```
    <td>Wireless <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="wireless" /></td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cellular <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="cellular" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Security <input type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="Security" /></td>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

and then I extract($_POST), and have this code

```
$comServices = implode(",", $services);
```

but I get an error:

> Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in ..

does anyone know why Im getting this error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If none of your checkboxes was selected $services would be undefined rather than an empty array.

You can do `$comServices = implode(",", (array)$services);` to prevent it.

Comment: thanks man this worked! Ill accept this answer when the time limit expires

Comment: You might want to use isset() to prevent warnings.

Comment: I'll put an exception where if its empty $comservices = "none" thanks again

Answer (score 2):

`$services` will be empty when there is no check box checked (empty as in `null`, not as in "an empty array").

You'd have to test whether $services actually is an array:

```
if (is_array($services))
 $comServices = implode(",", $services)
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, that means your variable is not an array... You can check for it with the is_array() function...